# Firebase storage rules cause user does not have access

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am trying to load a user profile image from firebase storage but I keep running into Cause (1 of 1):

> class com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: User does not have permission to access this object.

Authenticating user with:

```
mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(mEmailView.getText().toString(), mPasswordView.getText().toString())
```

Here are my firebase rules :

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/brainbeats-e9839.appspot.com/o {
    match /user/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Loading with glide like this:

```
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    StorageReference imageStorage = storageReference.child("images/" + user.getArtistProfileImage());

    GlideApp.with(this)
            .load(imageStorage)
            .into(mArtistCoverImage);
```

Comment: It'll be hard for anyone to say more than what the error message says without seeing how you create and initialize `imageStorage`.

Comment: have you used the FirebaseAuth to log the user in? If not, for simple testing, use sign in anonymously and then use it until you start using other methods 
.  refer https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Answer (score 0):

Well your rule grants access for the following :

```
/user/{userId}/{allPaths=**}
```

so any path under user then a userid location and then anything

But you are accessing

```
/images/xyzpath
```

Now since this isn't under /user/ variable userid/ , you get an exception.

why not shift images under user node like :

```
/user/{userId}/images/yourpath
```

This should stop giving errors if the auth rule matches. If it's an unauthorized user accessing another userid, it will still crash so best put everything in a try catch block